# Copy S3 data to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift COPY command to load the data into REDSHIFT from S3 bucket. There is a separate process which writes the data to the same S3 bucket. I'm not sure about the behavior of redshift in this case.

Is it possible that redshift load will not complete if we are writing to S3 bucket at very high rate?

I can move the files to other bucket and then load it from there. Can the same thing happen with copy command too? I can't use manifest.

Comment: I suggest that you think about loading your data in batches, separated by e.g. 15 minutes. you could then call you s3 folder something to denote which 15 minute batch you were loading.

Comment: Hi Jon, I am publishing to S3 bucket in batches (15 minutes using Firehose publisher). I drop my table everytime and then reload it again. This is being done because auto expiry is set for folders in s3 bucket. So that we don't need to do complex operation in table to remove these records.

Comment: Would it make sense to use Kinesis Firehose to deliver data to Redshift?